# Create account with Tor

Tags: configuration, anonymity

I am totally new and not very tech-affine.
I want to create an account for instagram but anonymously as I only want to use it to follow certain people. But when I try, it keeps telling me that it fails to create an account, as it knows that I am using tor. 
What are ways to solve my problem, or maybe just some keywords of things I should learn. Or do I have to use VPN?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Instagram knows you are using Tor because it recognises the exit node your traffic is coming out of. Using a VPN can only be trusted as far as you trust the VPN provider. Initially, you can try requesting a new circuit from Tor, if Instagrams database of exit nodes is not complete you might find one that it doesn't recognise. Otherwise, you could use a public computer such as a library to sign up for your account and then access it later using Tor.